# phpfox ;_How to give href to variable in php

Tags: php

I want to display the variable with hyperlink. Does anyone know how to give? I have applied the below method for href:

```
<div style="width:50px;height:20px;float:right">
    <a href="#" onclick="$.ajaxCall('forum.UnFlag', 'user_id={$aThread.user_id} &thread_id={$aThread.thread_id} &rate_value=i', 'GET'); return false;">
            <button class="button" name="val[button]"  value="">$i </button>
    </a>
    <?php
            for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++)
            {
               echo "The number is ".$i."<br />";
            }
    ?>
</div>
```

if you need anything regarding this ask me..

Comment: do u want to echo the variable name = variable value?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    for ($i=0; $i <= 10; $i++)
    {
       echo "The number is <a href=".$i." rel="">".$i."</a><br />";
    }
?>
```

and change below wrap variable inside `php` code.

```
<button class="button" name="val[button]"  value=""><?php echo $i; ?></button>
```